# Having trouble creating several Gaussian basis functions

Tags: python

The Gaussian basis function is given by the following [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEhSn.png).
Essentially I am creating a data set made up of N = 25 observations of my `x_n` ranging from `[0 1]` and the my target value `function_s_noise`. Since the 24 gaussian basis functions will be used for a regression model I created a design matrix `phi` and when I plot them I should expect this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFiwH.png). However this is what I am [getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrDRf.png) when plotting `phi`.
I am mostly not sure what the values of `mu` and `s` need to be of the corresponding basis functions.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

x_n=np.arange(0,1,0.04) #[0,1]
function = np.sin(x_n*np.pi*2)
n = 25                                     # Number of data points
noise = np.random.normal(0.0, 0.01, n)        # Random Gaussian noise
# print(noise)
function_s_noise = function + noise

def gaussian_basis(x, mu, s=7):
    return np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*(s^2)))

M = 24

# Calculate design matrix Phi
phi = np.ones((x_n.shape[0], M))
for m in range(M-1):
    mu = m/M
    phi[:, m+1] = np.vectorize(gaussian_basis)(x_n, mu)
plt.plot(phi)
```

Comment: What, specifically, is your question?

Comment: well the `s` is obviously way too large. Should be more like `0.1`

Comment: My question what should I alter to be able to obtain a plot similar to the expected result as I am having trouble understanding why I obtained the result that I got when plotting `phi`. Also I tried to decrease the value of `s` as suggested but the equation accepts only `int` values.

Comment: This is a clear sign for another error: you used `^` instead of `**`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9DrknGXj

Comment: @user8408080 thank you I did not see that mistake. your code did perform as expected however I can only use 25 observations of `x_n` which is why I used `x_n = np.arange(0,1,0.04)` meanwhile you used 500

Comment: I only increased the sampling for the plotting; `n` is still 25.

Comment: Sorry if I am not understanding something that is probably obvious here but wouldn't that change the shape of my `function` to 500 and the random gaussian `noise` would have 25 points. Which would inevitably lead to a `ValueError` when added together. I guess what I am trying to understand is how can I work with 25 points but then at the end increase the sample to plot?